# Copy range as image and paste into Outlook (results small/blurry)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to copy a range of cells as a picture, put that picture in an email, then send the email with an Excel macro.

I'm able to do all of this, however the image comes out smaller/blurrier than the original. I've tried all sorts of copy/paste methods but the results are the same.

When I copy the picture manually with copy as picture (as shown on screen) without a macro, then paste into outlook using just ctrl+v, the image looks fine.

Any idea why this is happening?

Here's the code:

```
Sub SendMail()

Dim aOutlook As Object
Dim aEmail As Object
Dim rngeAddresses As Range, rngeCell As Range, strRecipients As String
Dim rngeData As Range

Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)
Set rngeData = Worksheets("Promo Sync").Range("A5:Y86")

'Copy Range
rngeData.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture


Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = aEmail.GetInspector.WordEditor

'Paste picture
aEmail.Display
wordDoc.Range.Paste

Set rngeAddresses = ActiveSheet.Range("AK2:AK23")

For Each rngeCell In rngeAddresses.Cells
strRecipients = strRecipients & ";" & rngeCell.Value
Next

'Set Subject
aEmail.Subject = "Promo Sync " & Now()
'Set Recipient
aEmail.To = strRecipients
'Send Mail
aEmail.Send

End Sub
```

Comment: use pastespecial method...

Comment: Tried that  with all of the datatype options listed here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197265.aspx

Comment: `CopyPicture`--> `Paste on ChartArea` --> `Save the image from Chart as jpg`--> `Attach Inline Image in mail body`. No blurs, no copy fail issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try **`rngeData.Copy`** Then **`wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdPasteEnhancedMetafile`**

This should give you good quality `wdPasteDataType`, similar to  <kbd>**Ctrl+V**</kbd>

*[WdPasteDataType Enumeration (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197265.aspx)*